# Issue on Injecting Data Attribute to an existing Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to inject clicked element attribute data `data-css` to data attribute of `color-box`? as you can see I am able to print it out in the console by

```
console.log(jQuery(this).data('css'));
```

But the

```
jQuery('.current-color').data('css', jQuery(this).data('css'));
```

is not setting the data attribute for target element `.current-color`

[image]

```js
jQuery(".color").on('click', function() {
  jQuery('.current-color').css('background', jQuery(this).data('color'));
  jQuery('.current-color').data('css', jQuery(this).data('css'));
  console.log(jQuery(this).data('css'));
  jQuery('.current-color-name').text(jQuery(this).find('.color-name').text());
});
```

```css
.color-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#eee;
    border:2px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="current-color" data-css="">
  <div class="color-box current-color-name">Orane</div>
</div>
<div class="colors">
  <div class="color-box color" data-css="red.css" data-color="#f44336">
    <div class="color-name">red</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use `.attr('data-css')` instead of `data('css')`

Comment: Thanks Mohamed but same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.attr('data-anything')` instead of `.data('anything')` It works here

```js
$(".color").on('click', function() {
  $('.current-color').css('background', $(this).attr('data-color'));
  $('.current-color').attr('data-css', $(this).attr('data-css'));
  console.log($(this).attr('data-css'));
  $('.current-color-name').text($(this).find('.color-name').text());
});
```

```css
.color-box {
    width: 100px;;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#eee;
    border:2px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="current-color" data-css="">
  <div class="color-box current-color-name"></div>
</div>
<div class="colors">
  <div class="color-box color" data-css="red.css" data-color="#f44336">
    <div class="color-name">red</div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-box color" data-css="orange.css" data-color="orange">
    <div class="color-name">Orange</div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-box color" data-css="blue.css" data-color="blue">
    <div class="color-name">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're totally welcome @JJBOBO .. but let me say somethings I noticed in your image above.. 1st: include the line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`inside `<head>` OR before `</body>` if you include it before `</body>` you'll need to wrap your js code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code,clicks,event goes here})` .. 2nd: using `$()` instead of `jQuery()` will make the code looks simple to read and more clear .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 'data-' atrribute could not work was that when you first used the $('..').data('  ') method to get  the attribute value after you set it by 
$('..').data('  ','  ') method,jquery stored the value so that when you clicked again,the value had not changed.
 
  I thought reason was more important than solution for a developer.I hoped this could help.